# How to write certain parts of web scraped data into Excel cell by cell?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I am new to the Python and this is my very first project with it. So far I have managed to code using Youtube tutorials etc. but now I decided to ask for help here. Any kind of help is appreciated!
So I'm making a webscraper that scrapes data from a website, parses it nicely and writes the scraped data to an Excel file.

So far the scraper does write the data into an Excel file. But the problem is that I want the data to be written cell by cell so that Excel is able to work its magic.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

f = open('Book1.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(f)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://naturalstattrick.com').read(), 'lxml')
tbody = soup.findAll("table", {"class":"boxscore"})

for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [elm.text.strip() for elm in cols]
    writer.writerow(cols)
    print(cols)
```

Here is what I get:

Blues4Final1Bruins,"Corsi: 32, Fenwick: 25, Shots: 20, Scoring Chances: 18, High Danger Chances: 10, Expected Goals: 1.75
Corsi: 32, Fenwick: 25, Shots: 20, Scoring Chances: 18, High Danger Chances: 10, Expected Goals: 1.75
Corsi: 32, Fenwick: 25, Shots: 20, Scoring Chances: 18, High Danger Chances: 10, Expected Goals: 1.75
Corsi: 36.2, Fenwick: 27.99, Shots: 22.32, Scoring Chances: 20.13, High Danger Chances: 11.26, Expected Goals: 1.96
STL Wins 4 - 3
Corsi: 62, Fenwick: 41, Shots: 33, Scoring Chances: 21, High Danger Chances: 9, Expected Goals: 1.87
Corsi: 57, Fenwick: 38, Shots: 30, Scoring Chances: 18, High Danger Chances: 7, Expected Goals: 1.55
Corsi: 52, Fenwick: 34, Shots: 28, Scoring Chances: 17, High Danger Chances: 7, Expected Goals: 1.45
Corsi: 45.41, Fenwick: 29.99, Shots: 24.96, Scoring Chances: 15.11, High Danger Chances: 6.24, Expected Goals: 1.28"

Problem:
The data is written into 9 different cells altogether.

Goal:
I want this data to be sorted in their own (cells), such as:
(Blues) (4) (1) (Bruins) (32) (25) (20) (18) (10) (1.75)
so that all the values are located in their own cells in Excel.

Again, any help is useful and appreciated!

Comment: As there are not many items perhaps you could mock up in Excel what the final output should look like. For me, at least, your goal section doesn't give me a clear enough idea of how the final result should look. Not sure if you can post images but you should be able to post a link to an image that someone can then add in as an image for you.

Comment: just use pandas here since it's a `<table>` tag: `df = pd.read_html('http://naturalstattrick.com')[0]` then write to csv: `df = to_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: I hope this clarifies my plans: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IC5EwTA5XKXJU73JhXf2WZeS1TPKnwMw3aP1CMx10UE/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: So this Excel would be a file that updates itself as the season goes on, not overwrites the previously wrote data.